# Keeping my database updated every 30 minutes using Log files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactional-replication

I have a situation where I get a full nightly backup and trans log backup every 30minutes starts at 7:00 am ends at 2:00 am. I need to restore them every 30 minutes into a database and replicate this data into another database, so every next 30 minutes I should be able to restore the log files and keep the database in usable state to replicate this data to another database. I think we cannot use the database while restoring log files, but is there any process to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: This article from Brent Ozar (Kendra Little) has more details for you.  It is possible to do it, but probably shouldn't.  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/01/reporting-log-shipping-secondary-standby-mode/

Answer (score 1):

With log shipping you can do this. However, during the restore, the connection will be on hold. Query resulting is delay. Unfortunately, log shipping in there is no such solution.